# margin bottom doesn't want to work

Tags: css, html, margin

I have an "outside" div which takes 100% of the page. With a higher z-index value, I have an "inside" div. I don't know why but margin-bottom doesn't seem to work with this "inside" div.

My code is:

```
<style type="text/css">

#inside{
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:20%;
    width:60%;
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    z-index:3;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px black; 
}


#outside{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
    z-index:2;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
</style>

<div id="outside"></div>
<div id="inside">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/EnHut/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

Change position to relative
http://jsfiddle.net/EnHut/2/

```
#inside{
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:20%;
  height: 700px;
  width:60%;
  margin-top:35px;
  margin-bottom:35px;
  z-index:3;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px black; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` for `#inside`

http://jsfiddle.net/EnHut/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#inside{
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:20%;
    width:60%;
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    z-index:3;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px black; 
}
```

It is your position — you're using absolute, and the element don't know where it is to give margin at the bottom.

To see the difference between relative and absolute, [just click here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

[And here is the resolution of the problem in practice. (FiddleJs)](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/EnHut/3/)